System.IO.FileNotFOundException for assembly that lives in the folder for my unit test project?
I am building a project for Revit and now want to build unit tests for my C# code. The issue I am running into is that whenever I actually build the project and reference my project I get an error saying it cannot find the revit api dll. This makes no sense because the exact path saying where it can't find it is sitting right there.

System.IO.FileNotFoundException : Could not load file or assembly 'C:\Users\Joshua\source\repos\revit-addin-qa-testing-tool-backend\WebViewUnitTest\bin\Debug\net8.0\RevitAPI.dll'. The specified module could not be found.

When I use file explorer to find that path it lives right there

Does anyone have any idea why this may be happening?

what is your target path? copy local? bin\debug... building for release??

This could be an issue with x86 and x64 DLLs. an x64 process cannot load x86 DLLs and vice versa.

This could be due to specifying the wrong .NET framework target. Revit 2024 and prior require .NET framework 4.8; Revit 2025 requires .NET Core 8. Pay attention to the development requirements specified in the developer guide.
